# MuleSoft AWS SDK -- Cross Account trust (assumeRole)

Tags: aws-sdk, mulesoft, cloudhub, assume-role

We are trying to use AWS Parameter store for storing the username/passwords and access those parameters from MuleSoft CloudHub.

MuleSoft CloudHub in the background uses AWS Instances for deploying the applications to Workers.

So my question is can we do Cross Account Trust and we would assumeRole and grant access.

In this article (https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Default-AWS-Credentials-Provider-Chain-in-S3-connector) its mentioned that we can use cross-account but it doesnt work on CloudHub , can someone confirm that ?

Anyone done this before ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudHub doesn't provide access to the infrastructure directly so you can not set the environment variables as the article mentions:

> this is only possible in Runtime environments running the customers
> owned servers not in CloudHub, as customers don't have control over
> the environment of CloudHub workers.

Note that whatever connector implementation you are using to access AWS Parameter has to resolve that trust like the Mule S3 connector.